# Gradle trump providedCompile's exclusion?

Tags: gradle

I've got a project that I want to use providedCompile with to avoid pulling it's libs. However, that prevents me from pulling in another project's libs that I do need. The docs say: *If you don't want this transitive behavior, simply declare your provided dependencies*, but it doesn't give an example of how to do this.

Here's basically what my dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(':common'))
    providedCompile(project(':projA')) // <-- also depends on :common
}
```

My war file correctly excludes all of transitive libs from projA, but I need to trump that for the common.jar and I can't figure out how to make that happen. But the docs seem to indicate it's possible...

Edit: Here's a hacky configuration that seems to work. The combination of lines for "projA" gives me projA.jar as a dependency, but not its children. And since "common" is a compile dependency, but "projA" is only considered *provided* at runtime, I still get the common.jar due to the *compile* time dependency. I'm not sure it's supposed to work this way, but it generates the war I need.

```
dependencies {
    compile(project(':projA')) { transitive = false }
    providedRuntime(project(':projA')) { transitive = false }
    compile(project(':common'))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> If you don't want this transitive behavior, simply declare your provided dependencies

This means that if you don't want all dependencies of projA to be declared provided you need to list them as provided one by one.

From the Gradle 1.8 Userguide '26.4. Dependency management'

> The War plugin adds two dependency configurations: providedCompile and
>   providedRuntime. Those configurations have the same scope as the
>   respective compile and runtime configurations, except that they are
>   not added to the WAR archive. It is important to note that those
>   provided configurations work transitively.
>   Let's say you add commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.0 to any of
>   the provided configurations. This dependency has a dependency on
>   commons-codec. This means neither httpclient nor commons-codec is
>   added to your WAR, even if commons-codec were an explicit dependency
>   of your compile configuration. If you don't want this transitive
>   behavior, simply declare your provided dependencies like
>   commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.0@jar.

Comment: Ugh, that sucks. There are dozens of jars I'll have to declare one at a time.

Comment: You could try excluding common from the providedCompile declaration `providedCompile(project(':projA')){ exclude project(':common') }` but I don't know if it will work.

Comment: @ChrisKessel did you try it out?

Comment: Yes and no. The idea of having to exclude the subjars one at a time was painful, plus I didn't want to have to update my project every time "projA" added a new jar. So I hacked at it and found something that works. I've updated the original question with the hack/solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is another better solution that seems to be working. With `transitive=false` you exclude all the transitive dependencies that are then missing during compilation time and you have to declare all of them manually (again as provided) which is pain if they also include your desired library.

So for the providedCompile statement exclude not all transitive dependencies but only the one you want to include in war by separate compile statement.

Real example where I need the commons-codec included in the war file but that one is placed also in the keycloak-services and keycloak-model-jpa:

```
providedCompile         ("org.keycloak:keycloak-model-jpa:6.0.1") {
    exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
}
providedCompile         ("org.keycloak:keycloak-services:6.0.1") {
    exclude group: 'commons-codec', module: 'commons-codec'
}
providedCompile         "org.keycloak:keycloak-core:6.0.1"
providedCompile         "org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi:6.0.1"
providedCompile         "org.keycloak:keycloak-server-spi-private:6.0.1"
compile                 "commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10"
```

Comment: IMO this should be mentioned in the docs!